# Elasticsearch performance index with alias

Tags: performance, indexing, elasticsearch, alias

I'd like to use Elasticsearch and i think it is a good idea to set an Index like that: . I want to use one shard per index and to make a query over all years I made an alias  and put all new Index for every month per costumer into it. 
I just use one shard per index because they data per month could be between  ~ 1GB to 10-50+ GB.

My question: Is my planing good or is it bad? any recommendation? 
For example I collect data over 2 years and search with an alias , ES has to go through 24 Indexes. Does this make any performance problems? I could index per year but then i need to make more shards per costumer and some of them could be very small (to many shards for just a few GB) and others will be very big (e.g. 10 shards and over 50 GB per Shard, the index is very big). 
Thanks in advance!